# Jquery,php form not sending post data with .submit()

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have an upload page with an invisible input that i acitvated when you click on a picture and after a file is selected i want javascript to submit the form to another page but on the other page $_FILES['file'] is empty

my upload page:

form:

```
<form style="visibility: hidden;" id="target" method='POST' action="otherpage.php">
            <input type="file" id="file" value="Go" name="file" />
</form>
```

javascript

```
            function updatebillede() {
                $('input[type="file"]').click();
            };
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.val() != '') {
                        $("#target").submit();
                    } else {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

my other page

```
<?php print_r($_FILES['file']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in form attributes